# function of measurable random variable is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable that is measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$.

Is it true that a function of $X$ must also be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$?

For example, would $e^X$ be measurable here? I believe that it would be, although I am not sure how to demonstrate this.

Comment: If the function is measurable too, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easily follows from the definition of a measurable map that the composition of two measurable maps is itself measurable. So any **measurable** map of $X$ would be measurable with respect to $\mathcal F$.

However, a non-measurable map of $X$ is not necessarily measurable.